# How does this ICommand property work?

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I would appreciate help with the following code:

```
public static ICommand AddNewRecord { get; set; }
```

The above code is in the App.xaml.cs file of a WPF application.  What I don't understand: If I'm correct, an interface cannot be instantiated.  So what does the above property do?

Here's code that uses the above property (if that's what it is):

```
AddNewRecord = new RCommand<IEnumerable>(list =>
  {
    var elementType = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // More code I can't disclose.

  }, list => list != null);
```

I am not at liberty to provide the entire code segment.

Comment: "An interface cannot be instantiated" you are exactly correct, yet the interface is never instantiated in the provided code

Comment: `RCommand` implements `ICommand` so you can do `ICommand command = new RCommand()....` You cannot however do `ICommand command = new ICommand()`. Interface is just a implementation

Comment: This is a C# question, not a WPF question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, but I initally felt that the code being in an App.xaml.cs file might have something to do w/ it.

Comment: @12seconds Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RCommand<IEnumerable>` is a concrete type that implements the `ICommand` interface and you can set an `ICommand` property to any type that implements the `ICommand` interface.

So the code basically creates an `RCommand<IEnumerable>` and sets the `AddNewRecord` property to it.

The `RCommand<IEnumerable>` class in turn seems to accept an `Action<IEnumerable>` that gets invoked when the command is executed and a `Predicate<IEnumerable>` that will be returned from the `CanExecute` method of the command.